# Save LightGbm model in R and load it in C#

Tags: c#, r, lightgbm

I would like to:

1. train my model in R
2. Save the model in a file
3. Load the model in C# and use it to predict

The problem is that the file format in R (json) is not the same as in C# (zip)

Comment: You’re not likely to get a satisfactory answer if you fail the [MCVE] expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that the file format in R (json)

`{lightgbm}`, the official R package for LightGBM, supports other options besides JSON.

Use the following code in `{lightgbm} >= 3.3.3` to train a model and save it to the official LightGBM text model representation.

```r
library(lightgbm)

data(EuStockMarkets)
stockDF <- as.data.frame(EuStockMarkets)

# create a Dataset
feature_names <- c("SMI", "CAC", "FTSE")
target_name <- "DAX"
X_train <- data.matrix(stockDF[, feature_names])
y_train <- stockDF[[target_name]]
dtrain <- lightgbm::lgb.Dataset(
    data = X_train
    , label = y_train
    , colnames = feature_names
)

# train
model <- lightgbm::lgb.train(
    obj = "regression"
    , data = dtrain
    , verbose= 1
    , nrounds = 10
)

# save to a text file
lightgbm::lgb.save(
    booster = model
    , filename = "regression-model.txt"
)
```

That text file can be read by public entrypoint `LGBM_BoosterCreateFromModelfile()` in LightGBM's C API ([code link](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/60c92a969a0075cd271d55e40b611aaf52b061ed/src/c_api.cpp#L1728)), and therefore by any `C#` bindings that call that entrypoint.

For example, see `Booster.CreateFromModelfile()` in `LightGBMSharp`, a `C#` interface to LightGBM ([code link](https://github.com/ttustonic/LightGBMSharp/blob/3aaf7739399f68d5d05208ba99d002051449a420/LightGBM/Booster.WrappedMethods.cs#L19)).